# IIS ping fine but not loading in browser

Tags: iis, iis-6

I am pinging a computer that should be running IIS and the name we have attached it to responds to pings but when I go to a browsers it says no page found.

How can I verify that IIS is running and properly configured on this server?

Comment: @David: The operating system is responding to the ping, it does not mean that IIS is running, or if it is running that it is properly configured. You're probably better off on serverfault where they can help you get IIS running and configured to respond to requests.

Comment: Found httperr1.log has Connection_Dropped and Connection_Abandoned_by_appPool

Comment: what was the solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

This probably means that the name is mapped in DNS correctly and the machine is "up" but there may be a firewall issue blocking port 80. Try

```
telnet <domain name> 80
```

from a command line. If there is no response, make sure the site is set up in IIS and running and that there are no firewall issues.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to **Windows Firewall**.  Please verify/do the following:

1. Check if **Windows Firewall** is enabled.  You can do this by opening your **Control Panel**.
2. In the **Control Panel -> Windows Firewall** dialog, click on the **Advanced** tab.  In the **Network Connection Settings** section, click on the **Settings...** button.  Please verify that the **Web Server (HTTP)** option is checked.
3. You may also want to verify that TCP Port 80 is listed as an exception within the **Windows Firewall** **Exceptions** tab.

Comment: did this but no change

Answer (score 0):

I did the telnet thing and got 400 Bad request headers.

I also followed the firewall changes but still no luck.

Any other ideas?

-- edit --

Ok, now I was getting html pages and not php but then IIS would not restart so I restarted the server and now when I go to it via a browser it just sits there and spins.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your website is actually pointing to a directory which contains a web-type file (html, apsx, ect.).  Is IIS bound to one IP or any IP?  If bound to any and there are multiple IP's on the machine, you may have a conflict there.

Comment: It says no bounds but it is set to one ip

Answer (score 0):

Does it work from other PCs?

Or test via http://www.alertfox.com/?section=ToolsCheckView

Comment: this is an intranet app so we do not have to see it from the outside

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to a website running an ASP.NET application (ex. default.aspx) then make sure you have allowed .NET 2.0 to run in the IIS Site Properties.